# How to use findall or search to extract data in python?

Tags: python, regex

Here is my string,

```
str = 'A:[{type:"mb",id:9,name:"John",url:"/mb9/",cur:0,num:83498},
{type:"mb",id:92,name:"Mary",url:"/mb92/",cur:0,num:404},
{type:"mb",id:97,name:"Dan",url:"/mb97/",cur:0,num:139},
{type:"mb",id:268,name:"Jennifer",url:"/mb268/",cur:0,num:0},
{type:"mb",id:289,name:"Mike",url:"/mb289/",cur:0,num:0}],B:
[{type:"mb",id:157,name:"Sue",url:"/mb157/",cur:0,num:35200},
{type:"mb",id:3,name:"Rob",url:"/mb3/",cur:0,num:103047},
{type:"mb",id:2,name:"Tracy",url:"/mb2/",cur:0,num:87946},
{type:"mb",id:26,name:"Jenny",url:"/mb26/",cur:0,num:74870},
{type:"mb",id:5,name:"Florence",url:"/mb5/",cur:0,num:37261},
{type:"mb",id:127,name:"Peter",url:"/mb127/",cur:0,num:63711},
{type:"mb",id:15,name:"Grace",url:"/mb15/",cur:0,num:63243},
{type:"mb",id:82,name:"Tony",url:"/mb82/",cur:0,num:6471},
{type:"mb",id:236,name:"Lisa",url:"/mb236/",cur:0,num:4883}]'
```

I want to use findall or search to extract all the data under "name" and "url" from str. Here is what I did,

```
pattern = re.comile(r'type:(.*),id:(.*),name:(.*),url:(.*),cur:(.*),num:
(.*)')

for (v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6) in re.findall(pattern, str):
    print v3
    print v4
```

But unfortunately, this doesn't do what I want. Is there anything wrong? Thanks for your inputs.

Comment: (1) You should show what the code returns. (2) Read about greedy/non-greedy regex qualifiers.

Comment: Where does this string come from? Looks like JSON (except the opening and closing `{}` seem to be missing). If so, use the `json` module instead of regexes to parse it.

Comment: Actually if using non-greedy regex qualifiers, then only the first name and url, that is, 'John' and '/mb9/' are returned. And if using greedy regex qualifiers, then the whole string is returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't call you string "str," because that's a built-in function. But here's an option for you:

```
# Find all of the entries
x = re.findall('(?<![AB]:)(?<=:).*?(?=[,}])', s)

['"mb"', '9', '"John"', '"/mb9/"', '0', '83498', '"mb"', '92', '"Mary"', 
'"/mb92/"', '0', '404', '"mb"', '97', '"Dan"', '"/mb97/"', '0', '139', 
'"mb"', '268', '"Jennifer"', '"/mb268/"', '0', '0', '"mb"', '289', '"Mike"', 
'"/mb289/"', '0', '0', '"mb"', '157', '"Sue"', '"/mb157/"', '0', '35200', 
'"mb"', '3', '"Rob"', '"/mb3/"', '0', '103047', '"mb"', '2', '"Tracy"', 
'"/mb2/"', '0', '87946', '"mb"', '26', '"Jenny"', '"/mb26/"', '0', '74870', 
'"mb"', '5', '"Florence"', '"/mb5/"', '0', '37261', '"mb"', '127', '"Peter"', 
'"/mb127/"', '0', '63711', '"mb"', '15', '"Grace"', '"/mb15/"', '0', '63243', 
'"mb"', '82', '"Tony"', '"/mb82/"', '0', '6471', '"mb"', '236', '"Lisa"', 
'"/mb236/"', '0', '4883']

# Break up into each section
y = []
for i in range(0, len(x), 6):
    y.append(x[i:i+6])

[['"mb"', '9', '"John"', '"/mb9/"', '0', '83498']
['"mb"', '92', '"Mary"', '"/mb92/"', '0', '404']
['"mb"', '97', '"Dan"', '"/mb97/"', '0', '139']
['"mb"', '268', '"Jennifer"', '"/mb268/"', '0', '0']
['"mb"', '289', '"Mike"', '"/mb289/"', '0', '0']
['"mb"', '157', '"Sue"', '"/mb157/"', '0', '35200']
['"mb"', '3', '"Rob"', '"/mb3/"', '0', '103047']
['"mb"', '2', '"Tracy"', '"/mb2/"', '0', '87946']
['"mb"', '26', '"Jenny"', '"/mb26/"', '0', '74870']
['"mb"', '5', '"Florence"', '"/mb5/"', '0', '37261']
['"mb"', '127', '"Peter"', '"/mb127/"', '0', '63711']
['"mb"', '15', '"Grace"', '"/mb15/"', '0', '63243']
['"mb"', '82', '"Tony"', '"/mb82/"', '0', '6471']
['"mb"', '236', '"Lisa"', '"/mb236/"', '0', '4883']]

# Name is 3rd value in each list and url is 4th
for i in y:
    name = i[2]
    url = i[3]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import re
data = """
A:[{type:"mb",id:9,name:"John",url:"/mb9/",cur:0,num:83498},
{type:"mb",id:92,name:"Mary",url:"/mb92/",cur:0,num:404},
{type:"mb",id:97,name:"Dan",url:"/mb97/",cur:0,num:139},
{type:"mb",id:268,name:"Jennifer",url:"/mb268/",cur:0,num:0},
{type:"mb",id:289,name:"Mike",url:"/mb289/",cur:0,num:0}],B:
[{type:"mb",id:157,name:"Sue",url:"/mb157/",cur:0,num:35200},
{type:"mb",id:3,name:"Rob",url:"/mb3/",cur:0,num:103047},
{type:"mb",id:2,name:"Tracy",url:"/mb2/",cur:0,num:87946},
{type:"mb",id:26,name:"Jenny",url:"/mb26/",cur:0,num:74870},
{type:"mb",id:5,name:"Florence",url:"/mb5/",cur:0,num:37261},
{type:"mb",id:127,name:"Peter",url:"/mb127/",cur:0,num:63711},
{type:"mb",id:15,name:"Grace",url:"/mb15/",cur:0,num:63243},
{type:"mb",id:82,name:"Tony",url:"/mb82/",cur:0,num:6471},
{type:"mb",id:236,name:"Lisa",url:"/mb236/",cur:0,num:4883}]
"""
full_data = [i[1:-1] for i in re.findall('(?<=name:)".*?"(?=,)|(?<=url:)".*?"(?=,)', data)]
final_data = [full_data[i]+":"+full_data[i+1] for i in range(0, len(full_data)-1, 2)]
print(full_data)
```

Output

```
['John:/mb9/', 'Mary:/mb92/', 'Dan:/mb97/', 'Jennifer:/mb268/', 'Mike:/mb289/', 'Sue:/mb157/', 'Rob:/mb3/', 'Tracy:/mb2/', 'Jenny:/mb26/', 'Florence:/mb5/', 'Peter:/mb127/', 'Grace:/mb15/', 'Tony:/mb82/', 'Lisa:/mb236/']
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you use one findall to extract data from both name and url? If I extract data for name and url separately, then I must lose the info that how each individual name and url are related.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have one question. Obviously the pattern you choose contains both name and url, but why the returned value is still either name or url? Why doesn't the ONE single returned value include both name and url?

Comment: @JohnChen the solution does return both the name and url. Would you like them combined, such as `"name, url"`? If not, what method did you have in mind?

Comment: Actually I meant in your solution the ONE single return value contains either name or url. I want the ONE single return value contains both name and url so that each individual name and url are always bound.

Comment: @JohnChen please see my recent edit and let me know if that is what you where looking for

Comment: Perfect! Thanks.

Comment: @JohnChen If this answer assisted you, please consider accepting it. Thanks!